# Razor RenderSection doesn't work

Tags: razor

I'm an experienced web developer who's been doing project management instead of development for a year, so I'm trying to jump back into it and learn Razor.  So far, it's been a dismal failure.

I created a new empty Razor web site in VS2012, and created the following files:

_MainLayout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Razor Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>@RenderBody()</div>
        <div>@RenderSection("testSection")</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ContentPage1.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "_MainLayout.cshtml";
}

<div>This is the content on the Razor Test Page.</div>
```

and TestSection.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "_MainLayout.cshtml"; 
}

@section TestSection {
    <h1>this is test section</h1>
}
```

When I try and run this page, I get the following error:

> Section not defined: "TestSection".

And idea what's happening?  This was supposed to be as ridiculously simple as I could get it.  Apparently it's *too* simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) should go inside your page not in separate cshtml

ContentPage1.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "_MainLayout.cshtml";
}
@section testSection {
    <h1>this is test section</h1>
}

<div>This is the content on the Razor Test Page.</div>
```

Or if you want separate `cshtml` for "section like" display use partial views instead.

Comment: Thank you.  None of the examples I've seen made this very clear (or I was looking at partial view examples and didn't realize the distinction.)

Comment: Seems the section name and RenderSection values are case sensitive.

Comment: @Aaron, For your information RenderSection and Section Name values are not case sensitive.